# Cleanest way to wrap Java static methods in a non-static object (refactoring to allow mocking)

Tags: java, kotlin, mockito

I'm working with Java and Kotlin, and the codebase has some legacy static logic which really should be in objects, but is too deeply tangled to make non-static now. I want to be able to cleanly test (using mocks of these static dependencies) some (non-static) classes that depend on this static logic, so I want to wrap the static logic classes in non-static dummy wrappers, i.e. instantiatable objects whose instance methods just call their static counterparts. I'll then mock these wrappers in unit tests (I don't want to just use static mocking).

The manual way to do this is for each static logic class `Foo` with method `public static void bar()`, define a new class `FooWrapper` with method `public void bar()` that just calls `Foo.bar()`, instantiate a `FooWrapper` at the top of my class, and switch all the current calls to `Foo.bar()` to instead call `fooWrapperInstance.bar()`.

The above works fine but involves a lot of **boring** `Wrapper` classes that do nothing but pass calls. Is there some syntactic sugar (either Java or Kotlin is fine, but it has to work with Java) that will create, or at least shorten, these wrapper classes for me? I'm familiar with Guava's [ForwardingObject](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingObject.html) but it seems to only work when the underlying logic is in an instance already, which mine is not.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way to write your wrappers would be to use the method references as follows.

Say you have this Java class

```
public class A {
    static String hello() {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Then you want to create a wrapper for it in Kotlin like this

```
class AKotlin {
    val hello = A::hello
}
```

Now `AKotlin::hello` will have the same signature as the static `A::hello` method, but will be an object method instead

Comment: That makes sense (and I think is the cleanest write-it-myself option), but what I'd really like is something that'll auto-generate the `AKotlin` class, or at least the `val hello = A::hello` mapping within the class. I'm trying to avoid having to map `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `...`, `fn` manually